# Paint segment of highcharts chart

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I wanted to paint the last part of a highcharts chart like in this image:

[Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXjTk.png)

Is this possible? If it's not, having those last datapoints in another color would also be a possible solutions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a plot band in an adequate place on a chart. Please, look at the example posted below.

```
plotBands: [{
  color: '#F4FA91',
  from: Date.UTC(2017, 2, 1),
  to: Date.UTC(2017, 2, 2)
}]
```

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.plotBands

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/d_paul/2z3Lb2zv/